# How can you say "to be cold" in Spanish? Usage of 'hacer', 'tener', 'estar'

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, verbos, modismos

I know the following phrases:

> It's cold (referring to the weather)
> <sub>Hace frío</sub>
>
> He's cold
> <sub>Tiene frío</sub>

But when *something* is cold, it seems that the expression is as follows:

> El café está frío

And you would not say:

> El café tiene frío

Question: can we ever say simply that 'she is cold'?

> Ella está fría

Is the rule as follows? Does it cover everything?

- **hacer** for the weather
- **tener** for people
- **estar** for things

My apologies if this is really obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's more or less as you said, although that's not the whole picture.

For the weather we say

> *Hace frío.* | *Hace calor.*

These are **impersonal** sentences; they have no grammatical subject, and the direct object is either *frío* or *calor* or a few phrases involving those nouns and modifiers, like *un calor terrible* or *un frío espantoso* (note the article).

For the internal feeling of heat or cold experienced by an animate subject (a person, but also maybe an animal), we say things like

> *Tengo frío. | Ellas tienen frío. | Tuvimos calor. | El gato tiene calor.*

These are regular sentences with a subject (implicit or explicit), the verb *tener* and a direct object: *frío* or *calor*. Again you can modify these, e.g. *Tuvimos un calor terrible* = "We were terribly hot" ("We experienced a terrible heat").

For inanimate things that cannot **subjectively experience** heat or cold, we can use either *estar* or *ser* plus an adjective (*frío*, *caliente*, etc.). This is a gigantic topic in itself but mostly the rule is that *estar* implies a temporal state, while *ser* implies an essential quality.

> *La piedra está fría.* ("The [=this] stone is [currently] cold.")
>   *La piedra es fría.* ("Stone is [essentially] cold.")

Using *estar/ser* + a temperature adjective with an animate object, like a person, can have several different meanings. For example:

> *Estás frío.* = "You are cold."

This suggests either the literal meaning "I have touched your skin and it's cold", "Your body is cold to the touch", or the figurative meaning "You are aloof, detached, silently angry; you behave coldly, you are distant", etc. It's the same for *caliente*.

*Ella está fría* (your example) is not right for your meaning. It would mean either "her body is cold", which without context suggests we're talking about a corpse, or "she's behaving coldly". If you just want to say that she feels cold (she's experiencing cold, and you know it or guess it because she has told you so or because she is shivering and rubbing her hands and the like), then there's only one way to say it, which is *Ella tiene frío*.*

You wouldn't ever say *El café tiene frío*, unless you were being playful or poetic, because a cup of coffee is a thing, not an animate being capable of experiencing temperature, and *tener frío/calor* is only use for that kind of subject. You need to say: *El café está frío*.

* Actually it's not the only way (you could say also *Ella siente frío* or *Ella está con frío*) but you get the point.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, it makes perfect sense now.